# The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 12, which is not compatible with this version 13.10

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, postgresql-12, postgresql-13, kubernetes-pvc

I am trying to run postgres:13-alpine in Kubernetes cluster.

I have next Kubernetes manifest

PV

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: open-imis-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
    app: postgres
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt/data
```

PVC

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: open-imis-pv-claim
  namespace: open-imis
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

Deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: open-imis-db
  namespace: open-imis
  labels:
    app: open-imis-db
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: open-imis-db
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
     labels:
        app: open-imis-db
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: postgres:13-alpine
          name: open-imis-db
          env:
            - name: open-imis-secret
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: open-imis-secret
                  key: password
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
              name: postgres
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgres
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      volumes:
        - name: postgres
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: open-imis-pv-claim
```

More details in the [Pull Request](https://github.com/GovStackWorkingGroup/sandbox-open-imis/pull/4/files)

Could you help me to figure out the reason why pod `CrashLoopBackOff` with next error:

```
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

2023-04-04 16:38:05.912 UTC [1] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2023-04-04 16:38:05.912 UTC [1] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 12, which is not compatible with this version 13.10.
```

I don't set explicitly PostgreSQL version 12 anywhere. Where does it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with a mount path
for 13 version I have to use

`mountPath: /var/lib/pgsql/data` not

`mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data`